# C program for calculating the value of e

Tags: c, series, infinite

I was assigned a Hw that required me to calculate the value of `e` via using the series:

> 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + ...1/n!

The value of `e` must be calculated until the value of `n` (entered by the user) is reached. Also, the value of `1/n!` must be calculated until it's value is smaller than `epsilon` (also entered by the user).

I wrote the code, but there are some errors that compiler is telling me errors such as relational comparisons, use of ';' etc. Could anyone please help me fix the error. Thank you in advance.

Below is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int factorial (int i)
{
    if (i==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return i*factorial(i-1);
}

int main(void) {

    int i,n;
    float e,ep;

    printf("what is the value of epsilon: ");
    scanf("%f",&ep);

    printf("what is the value of n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (i=1; i<=n, i++)
        e= 1+1/factorial(i);

    for(1/fatorial(i)<=ep)
        printf("The value of e for the entered value of epsilon and n:%f",e);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include the *actual* error messages produced by your compiler.

Comment: Neither of those for-loops have correct syntax, which should be *clearly* spelled out in whatever book or online text you're using to learn the language.

Comment: What I don't understand is, if *n* is a fixed value, how can you keep calculating the value of *1/n!* until it's value is smaller than *epsilon*?

Comment: You should read about [ask] a good question. There it is explained that you should include relevant error messages (preferably copied and pasted) in the body of your question. When you are asking others for help, you need to make efforts to communicate your problem clearly. This will help us avoid guessing and help you get better answers.

Comment: If you want help, please do not say you are getting error without explicitly showing the exact errors you are getting.

Comment: Assuming an `int` is 32 bits, the factorial function will only work for values up to `12`, since `13!` is greater than 6 billion. You need to think about how to write the code without computing the factorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more precision I would use `double` instead of `float`.

```
for (i=1; i<=n, i++)
    e= 1+1/factorial(i);
```

This is wrong, you are not adding to *e*, you are assigning always the last
value of the series, which is always 0 (except for *i = 1*). So your *e* will
always be 1.

`factorial` is a function that returns an `int`. A `int` divided by an `int` is
an `int` and in C anything *1/x* (for *x* > 1, *x* integer) is 0. You you to use
`1.0` or cast at least one of the arguments to `double` (or `float` if you are
using floats):

```
double e = 1; // initializing e

for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    e += 1.0/factorial(i);
```

> Also, the value of *1/n!* must be calculated until it's value is smaller than *epsilon*, also entered by the user.

I don't understand what that means, if *n* is a fixed value given by the user,
what do you keep calculating? Is this really what the exercise says?

My interpretation would be: if by *n* steps *|e_real - e_calculated| > epsilon*,
keep incrementing *n*, otherwise stop. That would be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t factorial (uint64_t i)
{
    if (i==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return i*factorial(i-1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    double e = 1;
    double epsilon;

    printf("what is the value of epsilon: ");
    scanf("%lf", &epsilon);

    printf("what is the value of n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int i = 1;
    while(1)
    {
        e += 1.0/factorial(i++);

        if(i >= n && (fabs(e - M_E) < epsilon))
            break;
    }

    printf("e: %.20lf, calculated e: %.20lf, error: %.20lf, steps: %d\n", M_E, e, fabs(e-M_E), i);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: if you are using GCC, you have to compile it with the `-lm` option:

```
$ gcc e.c -oe -lm
```

Comment: My interpretation would be "keep adding until the addend becomes smaller than epsilon". Comparing the sum with _real e_ would be very strange.

Comment: @user58697 it seems we have different interpretations of what *epsilon* means. And I don't think it's strange to compare to the real value of *e*, I mean if you want to know the error margin, otherwise how do you compare how good your approximation was? I'm curious to know what is your interpretation of *epsilon* in the context?

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not summing the series but actually set e to 1.
2. Because you set it to e + 1/factorial(n) but your factorial() returns an int which is very likely to be above 1, so the division is integral, and 1 divided by any greater number will give 0.
3. The last loop is very strange. Did you mean `while` rather than `for`? Note that factorial is mistyped. Moreover, no work is done in the loop's body other than printing the same message over and over.